# Showing that if $f(x)=\inf\{|x-s|,s\in S\}$, f is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I would like some help with this, I've been trying to solve this exercise but I get stuck considering too many cases:

> Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}$, nonempty. Define $f(x)=\inf \{|x-s|:s\in S\}$. Prove that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated which cases you tried and why you got stuck on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Let $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Define $f(x)=d(x,S)=\inf\{d(x,s):s\in S\}$. Then use $$d(x,s)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,s)$$ to get what you want.

Comment: That was a quick typo-fix.

Comment: @DanielFischer =)